# Get Monthly-wise data using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

In my table `TimeTable` I've columns like `Title,FromDate,ToDate` etc., I'am trying to get the results in monthly basis. For this, I tried by using the Entity Framework like,

```
DataObject.Entities entities=new DataObject.Entities();

DataObject.TimeTable timeTable     
            = entities.TimeTables.First(t=>t.FromDate.Month<=DateTime.Now.Month 
                                && t.ToDate.Month>DateTime.Now.Month)
{ 
     //
}
```

but here, its showing error in the `t.FromDate.Month` its showing error like `<System.DateTime> doesn't contain definition for Month`......how can I fix this, can anyone help me here,

Comment: both FromDate and ToDate are of DateTime

Answer (score 2):

The problem it's that you're using methods which are part of the .Net framework and linq cannot translate. To handle with this issue tried like this

```
var example = entities.TimeTables.AsEnumerable().Where(
                            t=>t.FromDate.Month<=DateTime.Now.Month 
                            && t.ToDate.Month>DateTime.Now.Month);
```

This could work too

```
var example = entities.TimeTables.ToList().Where(
                            t=>t.FromDate.Month<=DateTime.Now.Month 
                            && t.ToDate.Month>DateTime.Now.Month);
```

**Note:** The second one will force you to get all record of your table will came result in a Bad performance if you had too many rows

Comment: Second option(one with ToLis()t) might not be optimal if TimeTables has lot of data. ToList will force query execution and load all the rows from table into memory and then filter